# Nuxt/Vue Application - direct page call of subpages generates a server error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, nuxt.js, internal-server-error

I have a project with the following problem:

If the page is accessed directly via the domain, you can switch to any subpage without an error. However, if a URL is called directly, e.g. https://impalawolfmitbiss.com/consulting, a server error is issued. This actually affects every subpage that is not called from the main page.

Error Logs:

- Apache server logs (500 GET /consulting HTTP/1.1)
- Chrome Console Network: 500 Internal Server Error

Since I rarely have to deal with such applications, I just want to ask in advance if this is a known problem and if anyone has any suggestions for a quick solution or Tips i can search.

a note: if I start the application locally, the problem does not occur.

Site: https://impalawolfmitbiss.com

Comment: Are you able to share a link to your source code? GitHub, or a codesandbox?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. The project is currently on Gitlab (private). Can I send you a link with the packaged project data? (by mail or otherwise)

Comment: You could invite me (nickdawes28) as a collaborator, if you're comfortable with that. I could clone your project, take a look, and if I'm able to help I'll answer the question here so others might benefit.

Comment: hy, i have create a new Github Account/Repo with the project. Have send you a Invite. 
Infos: the page is a one page site, the problem only occurs with the Onlnie version, not Local. the server is running node.js, all packages were reloaded from there as well
What i have currently changed: created a .htaccess file with redirection to the index but with the solution the content is not loaded on the first call. (have temporäry place the static project folder to server "_nuxt") but think this is also not the Solution. When i can help you with more infos just ask me

Comment: Apologies, I gave you the wrong github account. Please invite nickdawes.

Comment: Hy Nick, have sent the new invitation :-) thx for you time!

Comment: have remove the invite, the origin dev take a look to the projekt. 
Close.